# JQuery Validation not working correctly with MVC 3

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

The issue I'm having with jquery validation is that it doesn't like a dot notation in names.  I'm using the Microsoft HTML helpers that automatically create a name based on the view model and the name of the field.  So, for instance, the MS Html handler would generate "AuditDoc.Title" from an html textbox with the variable "Title" within the "AuditDoc" viewmodel.  My dilemma is that JQuery validation doesn't like that DOT in the middle of the name.  So when I put "AuditDoc.Title" as the name to validate against, it gives me a javascript error.  Any way around this?  I'd appreciate the help!

```
        $("#SaveCreateInProgress").click(function () {
        $("#AdvanceDirection").val("SAVE");
        $("#CreateInProgressMainForm").validate({
            rules: {
                AuditDoc.Title: "required",
                AuditDoc.ActivityId: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                AuditDoc.Title: "Please enter a Title (JQuery Validate)",
                AuditDoc.ActivityId: "Please select an Activity Id (JQuery Validate)"
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                alert("Submitted!");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting the quotes like

```
$("#SaveCreateInProgress").click(function () {
        $("#AdvanceDirection").val("SAVE");
        $("#CreateInProgressMainForm").validate({
            rules: {
                "AuditDoc.Title": "required",
                "AuditDoc.ActivityId": "required"
            },
            messages: {
                "AuditDoc.Title": "Please enter a Title (JQuery Validate)",
                "AuditDoc.ActivityId": "Please select an Activity Id (JQuery Validate)"
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                alert("Submitted!");
            }
        });
```

PS why dont you use the [unobtrusive validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html) that come with the MVC

edit

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/DWHjw/

Comment: I tried using the quotes like you suggested, but it still didn't work.  As for the unobtrusive validation, I'm not able to use the built-in MVC model validation since I have two different views sharing the same model.  It would take a ton of rework to mold it into a way that it would work with mvc validation.